# Changing font-family on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have a feature which allows user to change the font-family of the text inside a div, it kind of works. I will try to explain what is wrong hopefully you will understand.

- User clicks on font and select "Arial Black"
- Click on div, font changes.
- User clicks on "Times New Roman" Click on div, font changes.
- User clicks on google font "Lato" Click on div, font changes.
- User
  clicks on font "Arial Black" Click on div, nothing happens (I did
  console.log and both font and font2 are undefined at this point).
- It
  only starts to work again when user selects "Arial" and click on div.

  ```
  var originalFont = $('#fonts1').data('font');
  var originalgFont = $('#googlefonts1').data('font');
  var originalsFont = $('#fontsizes1').data('fontsize');
  var originalColor = $('#colorChoice').css('background', 'white');
  var textColor =$('#textColor').css('color', 'black');
  var font;
      $("#fonts1").on("change", function() {
              font = $(this).val();
      });
      $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
              $(this).css('font-family', font);
              console.log(font);
              font = originalFont;
      });
      var font2;
          $("#googlefonts1").on("change", function() {
              font2 = $(this).val();
      });
      $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
              $(this).css('font-family', font2);
              console.log(font2);
              font2 = originalgFont;
      });
  ```

  Load Fonts
          Hide Fonts

  ```
      <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Google fonts</button>
      <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
      <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>
  ```

Comment: Can you add the options to the select so we can test it?

Comment: I am using a library and the select options are generated, you can inspect them if you go to: https://www.webuilder.co.uk/ which is that website I post question about